# Converting C# code to Java

Tags: java, c#

So I tried to convert a piece of C# code to Java but I do not get same output when I use the converted code.

I already searched google and couldn't really find an answer. I' mostly interested in the Java equivalent of the TransformBlock method as I think that it is the one which causes problems.

C# code:

```
public class Sha256
{
    public Sha256()
    {
        sha = new SHA256Managed();
        sha.Initialize();
    }

    public void Process(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        sha.TransformBlock(data, 0, length, data, 0);
    }

    public void Process(uint data)
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);

        sha.TransformBlock(bytes, 0, 4, bytes, 0);
    }

    public void Process(string data)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        sha.TransformBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, bytes, 0);
    }

    public void Finish(byte[] data)
    {
        sha.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

        Digest = sha.Hash;
    }

    public void Finish(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
    {
        sha.TransformFinalBlock(data, offset, length);

        Digest = sha.Hash;
    }

    SHA256 sha;
    public byte[] Digest { get; private set; }
}
```

Java code:

```
public class Sha256 {

    public byte[] digest;
    private MessageDigest sha;

    public Sha256() {
        try {
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.logException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void process(byte[] data, int length) {
        sha.update(data, 0, length);
    }

    public void process(int data) {
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES).putInt(data).array();

        sha.update(bytes, 0, 4);
    }

    public void process(String data) {
        byte[] bytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        sha.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    public void finish(byte[] data) {
        sha.update(data, 0, data.length);

        digest = sha.digest();
    }

    public void finish(byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
        sha.update(data, offset, length);

        digest = sha.digest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the Java code also?

Comment: You have many different method calls in there, each one of which could change when you port to Java.  In any case, I don't think we can help you , because you didn't also show your Java code.

Comment: I posted the java code too

Comment: I realise this isn't an answer to your question, but dotnet has a Sha256 implementation already.  Why not use that?

Comment: I'm assuming you are getting different hashes for the same given input?

Comment: "I do not get same output" -- What do you get? What do you expect? For what input?

Comment: I assume C# is little endian by default, Java's ByteBuffer is big endian by default.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it seems that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: in few areas C# can be "ported", but here too much low level things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is little endian by default AFAIK. This is most likely as it was developed by Microsoft who in turn used x86/x64 machines where little endian is the default.

Java's ByteBuffer uses big endian by default. It was first developed on SPARC processors which are big endian.  There is couple of ways to swap the order of the bytes but the most natural is to use `ByteBuffer.order()` as below.

```
public void process(int data) {
    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES)
                             .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                             .putInt(data)
                             .array();

    sha.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```